# Problema ejecutando función desde AddEventListener

Tags: javascript

Primero que nada aclaro que estoy haciendo un curso introductorio a la programación.

Dicho esto, les cuento que estoy haciendo un proyecto para dicho curso, para el cual, entre otras cosas, hice una función que genera colores al azar y los pone en un array y esto determina el color de 6 cuadrados.

Lo que quise hacer, es crear un eventlistener para que cuando cliquees en un botón, se reseteen los colores, es decir, ejecute la función de generar colores randoms otra vez, pero no está funcionando lo que escribi..
¿Cuál creen que sea el error?

```
botonReset.addEventListener("click", generateRandomColors());   **(código con el que tengo problemas)**
```

```
function randomColor() {
  let r = (numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  let g = (numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  let b = (numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  let rgb = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
  return rgb;

function generateRandomColors() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    colores.push(randomColor());
  }
  return colores;  **(función que genera los colores randoms en el array)**
}
```

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: En la línea: `botonReset.addEventListener("click", generateRandomColors());` no le estás pasando la función en sí sino el resultado de esa función, por lo tanto, te genera error. Debe pasar la función sin los parentesis de apertura y cierre: `botonReset.addEventListener("click", generateRandomColors);` El return de tu función está demás. Supuestamente `colores` es una variable global.

Answer (score 0):

buenas! He notado algunos detalles que pueden ser la causa de tu problema.

En la función **generateRandomColors()** lo que estás haciendo dentro del **for** es generar 5 colores random y agregarlos al array de colores, es decir, no estás sustituyendo los existentes.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías resolverlo:

```
const botonReset = document.querySelector('#botonReset');

let colors = [];

botonReset.addEventListener("click", generateRandomColors);

function randomColor() {
  let r = (numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  let g = (numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  let b = (numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
  let rgb = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
  return rgb;
}

function generateRandomColors() {
  let newColors = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    newColors.push(randomColor());
  }
  
  colors = newColors;
}
```